# Updating SQL with PHP variables but not updating

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I've been experimenting using PHP and SQL to access a database to then be able to read and append to it.

My problem is that, however I set it out when I compared different ways to structure it. It doesn't update.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Test SET '$updateGet' = '$appendGet' WHERE id = '$idGet'" ;
```

What is the correct way without worrying about SQL injection? Also, any documentation on other ways to do this would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "jenk3194";
$password = "wlFfn1";
$dbname = "jenk3194";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$appendGet = ($_GET["appendSend"]); # WHAT TO APPEND
$idGet = ($_GET["idSend"]); # ID TO APPEND
$updateGet = ($_GET["updateSend"]); # WHAT TO UPDATE
#$sql = "UPDATE Test SET Projection = 999 WHERE id = 1";
$sql = "UPDATE Test SET '.$updateGet.' = '.$appendGet.' WHERE id = '.$idGet.'" ;
#$sql= sprintf("UPDATE Test SET %s = %d WHERE id = %d", $updateGet, $appendGet, $idGet);
echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: Could you post your whole code to update the database?

Comment: @MrDarkLynx It wont allow me as it says some code is formatted incorrectly but even when I did that, still the same error

Comment: You never execute the query. Have a look at `mysqli_query`. Also your code is open to **SQL injection**. Please use _prepared statements_.

Comment: @MrDarkLynx To begin with Id like to correctly update it without SQL injection being my main worry just a functioning code. So simply using the query($conn, $sql) would work?

Comment: @AlexJenkinson where do you execute the statement ?

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` I included this after I realised I removed it when checking my code

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Test SET '".$updateGet."' = '".$appendGet."' WHERE id = '".$idGet."';
```

You need to add the dots before and after php variable. If it the variable contains a string you also need to add the quotation marks.

Comment: Wouldn't that include the dots in the actual variable?

Comment: i edit the answer should now be correct. But MrDarkLynx is also correct as your not running the SQL either.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote something about injection so first of all you can use pdo statements as 1st security, but read up on this post [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Be safe and always check user input, it's not that if you're doing let's say email validation with your JS you can skip it in your PHP code. Security comes in layers.

Comment: motherhood and apple pies ... not even attempting to help OP.  That would have been a fine comment.

Comment: It does state that I am not worrying about SQL Injection as I'd like a working code.

Comment: @AlexJenkinson so that next you gonna post the same question, on how to prevent sql injections on t?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Possibly, as a forum full of experts in there fields is the best way

Comment: @YvesLeBorg well, your introduced much more content, didn't it? ; ) back to basics